# Trouble sorting labels using class Tkinter

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter

so, I'm trying to create a contacts book app for a school project using Tkinter. here's how it works:
user gives me a database(.db) and using sqlite3,u should put them automatically in labels and grid them to the screen but, I want to make a class out of each contact so I can use some functionality on them. so I tried making a class using this code(no functions yet):

```
class User(Label):
    def __init__(self,name, last_name, phone_number, email, id, row):
        self.frame = Frame(second_frame)
        self.frame.grid(row = row, column = 0)

        self.id_label = Label(self.frame, text = id, font = sub_font, bg = background_color, fg = sub_font_color)
        self.id_label.grid(row = row, column = 0)

        self.name_label = Label(self.frame, text = name, font = sub_font, bg = background_color, fg = sub_font_color)
        self.name_label.grid(row = row, column = 1)

        self.last_name_label = Label(self.frame, text = last_name, font = sub_font, bg = background_color, fg = sub_font_color)
        self.last_name_label.grid(row = row, column = 2)

        self.phone_number_label = Label(self.frame, text = phone_number, font = sub_font, bg = background_color, fg = sub_font_color)
        self.phone_number_label.grid(row = row, column = 3)

        self.email_label = Label(self.frame, text = email, font = sub_font, bg = background_color, fg = sub_font_color)
        self.email_label.grid(row = row, column = 4)
```

and I tested it and it all worked out in my (root) screen. but I wanted to make a frame so I could use scrollbars for the app but for that to happen, I should have made an main frame (named second_frame).
when I tried using it in that main frame(second_frame), it didn't work and put all the variables in column 1.[image]

here is how i make classes:

```
conn = sqlite3.connect("contacts_book.db")
cursor = conn.cursor()
cursor.execute("SELECT *,oid FROM contacts")
contacts = cursor.fetchall()
sub_row = design_row + 1
    
for contact in contacts:
    cont = User(contact[0], contact[1], contact[2], contact[3], contact[4], sub_row)
    sub_row += 1

conn.commit()
conn.close()
```

and here's how I made the second_frame:

```
# create a main_frame
main_frame = Frame(root, bg = background_color)
main_frame.pack(fill = BOTH , expand = 1)
# create a canvas
my_canvas = Canvas(main_frame, bg = background_color)
my_canvas.pack(side = LEFT,fill = BOTH, expand = 1)
#  add scrollbar to canvas
my_scrollbar = ttk.Scrollbar(main_frame , orient = VERTICAL, command = my_canvas.yview)
my_scrollbar.pack(side = RIGHT, fill = Y)
# config scrollbar
my_canvas.configure(yscrollcommand = my_scrollbar.set, bg = background_color)
my_canvas.bind("<Configure>", lambda e: my_canvas.configure(scrollregion = my_canvas.bbox("all")))
# create another frame in canvas
second_frame = Frame(my_canvas, bg = background_color)
# add that new frame in the canvas
my_canvas.create_window((0,0), window = second_frame, anchor = "nw")
```

what am I doing wrong? is that because I put them in second_frame or something? thanks for your help!

Comment: If you want everything in one big grid, you shouldn't be creating those individual Frames for each `User` object.  Each of those Frames would have its own grid system, there'd be no way to line anything up with the contents of separate Frames.

Comment: i put them in "second_frame" and it worked! thanks a lot.